# How can apparently nested Subversion working copies be coalesced? [Equivalently: How do I add the parent directory to source control?]

Tags: svn

I have a partially checked-out tree of sources. These were incorrectly checked out with commands like this:

```
> svn co --depth=empty svn://repos/trunk .
> svn co --depth=infinity svn://repos/trunk/project project
> svn co --depth=infinity svn://repos/trunk/test test
```

Of course, the commands should have been something like

```
> svn co --depth=empty svn://repos/trunk .
> svn up --set-depth=infinity project
> svn up --set-depth=infinity test
```

The resulting symptoms are:

```
> svn st
?       project
?       test
```

although

```
> svn info
Path: .
URL: svn://repos/trunk
Repository Root: svn://repos
Repository UUID: 01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef
Revision: 1234
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Depth: empty

> svn info project
Path: project
URL: svn://repos/trunk/project
Repository Root: svn://repos
Repository UUID: 01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef
Revision: 1234
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
```

(Curiously, the symptoms don't arise if the first command was `svn co --depth=immediates svn://repos/trunk .`.)

Now, the reason for the symptoms is that the file

```
./.svn/entries
```

does not contain entries for the `project` and `test` directories. (I can fix my problem by hacking directly into this file, but I'd really rather not.)

My question is:

**Is there a Subversion command to 'coalesce' these working copies so that `svn st` is silent (or shows local modifications in project and test)?**

I have tried various things, including

> svn up --set-depth=immediates --depth=empty .

but that doesn't work
because `--depth` and `--set-depth` "are mutually exclusive".

I have also tried

> svn up --set-depth=infinity project

but that doesn't work
because `project` is interpreted as a relative path locally rather than in the repository; that is, the URL is formed after rather than before application of the relative path to the current directory.

Worse still, I have tried

> svn up --set-depth=immediates .

but that has the unfortunate (but correct) effect of merrily removing files.

This question is more widely relevant than the circumstances I describe. Another situation that might call for this kind of 'fix' is if you wish to check out the parent of the uppermost node already checked out without having to re-checkout the sources that already exist locally, and whilst retaining any local modifications.

Thanks,
Rob.

Comment: Have you tried just `svn up`? `%)`

Comment: Yes. But I do not want to update my sources (which can easily be achieved in two steps). What I want to do is effectively add a (common) parent directory to source control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, coalescing such working copies is not possible in a supported way. I would simply make a fresh checkout to fix the situation.

Comment: This may be a good answer in the negative if there really is no supported way in which what I want to do can be achieved. I'm still hoping for a creative solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can copy incorrectly checked out sub-paths to another location, then correctly up with

```
svn up --set-depth=infinity project
svn up --set-depth=infinity project
```

then find a way to overwrite the files with saved in another location recursively, so they are now under a parent checkout

May be cat (linux) or type (Windows) will do.

Linux:

```
cat savedLocation/recursiveDir/file > recursiveDir/file
```

Windows:

```
type savedLocation/recursiveDir/file > recursiveDir/file
```

You can list the files with recursive directory with tree command on linux:

```
tree -if savedLocation/
```

Don't know how to do the same in Windows

Comment: Are you saying you could copy on top of a directory that has been checked out by running a check out on its parent with depth=immediates? That's an interesting trick.